# Private members in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please tell me how do we use or declare private members in javascript.I will appreciate an example.I am new to this

Answer (score 8):

Douglas Crockford has a write-up on [Private Members](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html):

Private members are made by the constructor. Ordinary vars and parameters of the constructor becomes the private members.

```
function Container(param) {
    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3;
    var that = this;
}
```

This constructor makes three private instance variables: param, secret, and that. They are attached to the object, but they are not accessible to the outside, nor are they accessible to the object's own public methods. They are accessible to private methods. Private methods are inner functions of the constructor.

```
function Container(param) {

    function dec() {
        if (secret > 0) {
            secret -= 1;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3;
    var that = this;
}
```

The private method dec examines the secret instance variable. If it is greater than zero, it decrements secret and returns true. Otherwise it returns false. It can be used to make this object limited to three uses.

By convention, we make a private that variable. This is used to make the object available to the private methods. This is a workaround for an error in the ECMAScript Language Specification which causes this to be set incorrectly for inner functions.

Private methods cannot be called by public methods. To make private methods useful, we need to introduce a privileged method.

Answer (score 4):

here is one way to do it:

```
function TheClass() {
    var _this = this;
    var privateMember = 'foo';
    this.publicMember = 'bar';

    var privateMethod = function(){
        // things happen here
    };

    this.publicMethod = function(){
        //other things here
        _this.publicMember = 'sparky';
        return privateMember;
    };
}

var myObj = new TheClass();

alert(myObj.privateMember);  //won't work
alert(myObj.publicMember);   //should work
alert(myObj.publicMethod()); //should work too
```

see this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RUt2b/2/) and play a bit with it ;)

Comment: Can you please explain your code,how this has made members private ?

Comment: `privateMember` and `privateMethod()` are accessable from Members of an instance of the class. `publicMember` and `publicMethod()` can be called from outside the class-scope. I`ll edit my answer to illustrate what i mean...

Comment: i've also added a example of realizing a way to implement classvars, also if many people are a bit sceptical about that. thee the fiddle referenced in the answer for that...

Comment: But I can still modify the value of your private field... 

myObj.privateMember = "modified";

Comment: You could do so even if there was no such property in advance. You wouldnt modify, you'd add the property. Try it with any other prop. It will always work.

Comment: Why did you assign _this and use it in publicMethod?

Comment: Its a habit i had before I used ES6 Arrow-Functions, because in JS, [`this doesn't always behave the way one would expect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). I think this was heavily promoted by Douglas Crockford.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have private variables per-say. In JS variables are scoped to the top of the closest function. So creating a function (or closure) is a way to make private variables only accessible within that scope. The important thing to remeber is to *always* use `var` to declare variables, otherwise, even inside a function, the variable will become global, and that's bad.

If you're working with prototype inheritance then it's as easy as creating a constructor and any variable declared with `var` will be private and declared with `this` will be public.

```
function Bar() {
  var foo = ''; // private
  this.baz = function() {}; // public
}

var bar = new Bar(); // create new instance of Bar
alert(bar.foo); // error
alert(bar.baz); // function
```

Also the above constructor is very simple, typically you'd put function methods on the actual `prototype` of the object, like `Bar.prototype.baz = function(){}`.

If you're working with a singleton for example, you can use the module pattern:

```
var bar = (function(){ // bar is public

  var foo = ''; // foo is private
  function baz() {}; // baz is private  

  return {
    baz: baz // expose 'baz' as a public member of 'bar'
  }

}());

alert(bar.foo); // error
alert(bar.baz); // function
```

Comment: Thanks man....add me on skype or facebook or gmail..lol
nirjhar18 at skype and gmail.
can you tell me some interview questions for javascript..i hav it tomorrow..wt shld i cover

Answer (score 1):

You can try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/private-members

This package will save the members by instance.

```
const pvt = require('private-members');
const _ = pvt();

let Exemplo = (function () {    
    function Exemplo() {
        _(this).msg = "Minha Mensagem";
    }

    _().mensagem = function() {
        return _(this).msg;
    }

    Exemplo.prototype.showMsg = function () {
        let msg = _(this).mensagem();
        console.log(msg);
    };

    return Exemplo;
})();

module.exports = Exemplo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Private members are made by the constructor. Ordinary vars and parameters of the constructor becomes the private members.

```
function Container(param) {
    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3;
    var that = this;
}
```

This constructor makes three private instance variables: param, secret, and that. They are attached to the object, but they are not accessible to the outside, nor are they accessible to the object's own public methods. They are accessible to private methods. Private methods are inner functions of the constructor.

You can find more details on [this link](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Comment: I have read that man..but how are these private now..you declare public also in the same way..this is the link you get

Comment: @AndroidHelp - They are private because they cannot be accessed outside of the function, without declaring them in the global scope first and not re-declaring them using `var`.

Answer (score 0):

The (currently draft) ECMAScript 2022 Specification includes the concept of private identifiers. See [Private class features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) on MDN:

> Class fields are public by default, but private class members can be created by using a hash # prefix. The privacy encapsulation of these class features is enforced by JavaScript itself.

Most popular JS engines already support it.

Example:

```js
class Animal {
    #owner;
    
    constructor(name, owner) {
        this.name = name;
        this.#owner = owner;
    }
    
    hasOwner() {
        return Boolean(this.#owner);
    }
}

let dog = new Animal("blacky", "trincot");
console.log(dog.hasOwner()); // true
console.log("#owner" in dog, "#owner" in Animal.prototype); // false, false
```